# I need to add endpoint for wordpress categories

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

Hello dear stackexchange team or user i want to state that I have a wordpress website like example.com and i has category like example.com/category/uncategorized.

Now i want to add a endpoint named new-post after the category without creating any page or child category.

Not even just for this category but also for every category.

It means i want to add endpoint for all categories available on my wordpress website.

Like after adding the endpoint my website category should be redirect a that particular category page.

For example for uncategorized category the permalink should be example.com/category/uncategorized/new-apps.

I have try ep_categories to add endpoint for categories but this not work.

Kindly help me this and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Isn't this standard behaviour for WordPress?  Or am I misunderstanding what you're asking?

Comment: What would the endpoint do? Do you want to post new content to this endpoint to create new posts in that category? It would be easier to post to the REST API instead, although you could make this work.